# Is that TLB contains only entries for a single process?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, tlb

Is that TLB contains only entries for a single process? So the **page table** in the following [line from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#The_translation_process) is belongs to certain process, which is maintained by operating system?

> The CPU's memory management unit (MMU) stores a cache of recently used mappings from the operating system's **page table**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely system specific. Some processors store a process ID with cache entries (multiple processes in the cache). Other processors require a cache flush with a process change (on process in the cache).